# macOS X Catalina cannot be installed on Macintosh HD

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition, catalina

I am currently on a Early 2015 Macbook Pro on El Capitan 10.11.6.

I am looking to update to Catalina but I get the error message in the title of this post. I got this error after doing diskutil verify disk. Before that I got the message that I am missing a firmware partition.

my diskutil list information is as follows:

```
/dev/disk0 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *960.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            959.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +8.4 GB     disk1
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
2:                  Apple_HFS InstallESD              8.1 GB     disk1s2
```

Update: Upgraded to Sierra. Cannot advance to High Sierra or Catalina due to the same missing firmware partition error.

Update 2: System Information says this:

```
Macintosh HD
Available:  920,7 GB (920.699.588.608 bytes)
  Capacity: 959,18 GB (959.180.382.208 bytes)
  Mount Point:  /
  File System:  Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Volume UUID:  FA831049-5446-3393-952B-D5EC501F181C
  Physical Drive:
  Device Name:  OWC Aura SSD
  Media Name:   OWC Aura SSD Media
  Medium Type:  Rotational
  Protocol: PCI
  Internal: No
  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
```

Comment: If you do not have a Time Machine backup, now would be a good time to make one.  That will allow you to let the installer scratch the internal harddisk and repartition it as it feels fit, and then restore your machine from the backup.

Comment: Could this be a storage space issue?  How much free space on your drive?  If you are trying to install Sierra it may need free space equal to the whole High Sierra Software package.

Comment: I've just done a wipe. So it has about 900+ gb free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a third-party internal SSD. You need an OWC firmware update in order to upgrade past High Sierra.

[Installing High Sierra on OWC Aura SSD - missing firmware partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321041/installing-high-sierra-on-owc-aura-ssd-missing-firmware-partition)

Comment: It says my drive is external but it's inside my Macbook? I'm not terribly clever with hardware but I'm pretty sure if it's inside my machine that's internal right? My Macbook is the same as when I got it day 1.

Comment: It should say "internal". What does System Information say? Is it possible there's a third-party aftermarket SSD installed?

Comment: Will update main post to say what system info says

Comment: @CalMac Updated my answer re your info.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You should probably upgrade to [High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969) first, then upgrade to Catalina. Installing High Sierra will upgrade the firmware. Also, High Sierra can boot from both JHFS+ and APFS partitions. Catalina can only boot from APFS which requires the Mac to have the firmware update. If you have a SSD, then the upgrade to High Sierra should also convert the boot partition to APFS. Otherwise, HDD will be converted after installing High Sierra.

Comment: I tried doing this but it wouldnt let me upgrade to High Sierra either. I upgraded to Sierra though and now cannot advance to High Sierra. Same issue.