Why is my Mac mini 2011 — with an SSD upgrade — stuck on grey screen during startup?
A colleague of mine gave me an old Mac mini (Mid 2011 2.5GHz, model A1347) that I wanted to put back to work mainly for fun.
The Mini came without an HDD, so I bought a new SSD (Samsung 870 Evo, 500GB) and installed it inside the Mac following the guide at iFixIt with no problems.
Then, I created a bootable USB flash drive with macOS High Sierra (10.13), known to be compatible with my model. However, when the loading bar below the Apple logo arrives to about 70%, my monitor seems to reset and a grey screen appears, and nothing else happens. I tried to leave it for some hours but nothing changed.
I also tried to boot from internet recovery: It successfully downloads the internet recovery image, but then after the loading bar arrives ~70%, it gets stuck on the same grey screen.
I also launched Apple Diagnostic (holding D and later Option+D during startup), run the "long" test and it says no troubles found.
I also tried the following:

Reset the NVRAM and SMC.
Boot with cmd+option+R, cmd+shift+option+R, and cmd+R (both with Wi-Fi and Ethernet)
Boot with cmd+S to get into single user mode: here everything seems ok, I run fsck on every /dev/disk* and it tells everything is fine. Then I type exit to continue the boot process, and it gets stuck to the same grey screen.
Boot with cmd+V (i.e. verbose mode), there don't appear to be errors where it gets stuck, instead, the screen again blinks and goes gray forever (same as above).
Tried to use the bootable USB stick with other OS versions, such as Yosemite (10.10), El Capitan (10.11), and Sierra (10.12).
Connected an HDMI display instead of DisplayPort from the Thunderbolt port.

None of these worked, the Mac always gets stuck to the grey screen. I do not think it has a discrete GPU, and even if it had it, I tried some boot-args to disable it with no success.
Is there anything else I can try to get this machine back to work?

I seem to remember something about High Sierra and firmware upgrades and third-party internal SSDs....?

@benwiggy I remember that SSDs with High Sierra should be formatted using APFS file system, and the firmware should update itself when you boot from a usb containing High Sierra. However I don't think it is the SSD's fault because it does not even boot from internet recovery

This post seems to cover thie issue. It may or may not be relevant. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321041/installing-high-sierra-on-owc-aura-ssd-missing-firmware-partition
