# Mojave and RAID

Tags: macos, mac, raid, mojave

Does anyone know if Mojave will support booting from RAID drives?

My MacPro 5,1 has RAID hard drives and two striped SSD's that boot into Sierra.  I've been unable to update to High Sierra on this configuration but maybe Mojave will, at last(!), solve the problem!!

Comment: It's not a Mojave issue, but rather an [APFS issue converting a RAID 0 array](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304328/119271).  There are workarounds like installing on a single drive then cloning to a RAID 0 volume.

Comment: Alan: thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried this and as you suggest got HS to load from a RAID disk BUT I couldn't thereafter load any updates and had to revert back to Sierra.

Comment: You can still run HS from HFS+, you just lose the advanced features of APFS.

Comment: @Allan so if we 1) Backup (using CCC, etc.)  2) Install HS/MJV to external backup  3) Wipe internal re-RAID and "restore" from backup . . . it works?  Do we, in fact, lose the ability to run future updates for any reason?  FYI, I don't care in the least about APFS, I simply want to extend the life of my MBP.